# Closedness of operator Hardy type

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am having difficulty proving that the operator
$$ Af(x) = \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt$$ is not a closed operator from $D(A) = C_c(0,1)$ to $L^2(0,1)$. Is there any easy way to see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can construct a sequence $f_n \in C^0_c(0,1)$ which converges to $0$ in $L^2(0,1)$, but for which $A f_n$ does not converge to $0$ in $L^2(0,1)$, by concentrating the mass of $f_n$ near $t = 0$.

For instance, let $F \in C^\infty(0,+\infty)$ be a non-negative function compactly supported in $(0,1)$. Take a sequence $0<\delta_n\ll 1$ and set $f_n(x) := F(x/\delta_n)$.

Then $\| f_n \|_{L^2} \to 0$ as soon as $\delta_n \to 0$.

Since $\operatorname{supp} F \subset (0,1)$, one has for $x \in [\delta_n,1]$,
$$
Af_n(x) = \int_0^{\delta_n} \frac{f_n(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t
= \int_0^1 \frac{F(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t =: \rho > 0.
$$
Simultaneously, for $x\in [0,\delta_n]$, $0 \leq Af_n(x) \leq \rho$.

Hence, as $\delta_n \to 0$, $Af_n$ converges (in $L^2(0,1)$) to the constant function $\rho$.

Comment: This shows that $A$ is not continuous from $(C_c(0,1), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ to $L^2(0,1)$, however the question seems to me rather like it's about proving (or disproving) that the operator is closed (aka proving or disproving that its graph is closed) from $C_c(0,1)$ seen as a dense subset of $(L^2(0,1), \|\cdot\|_{L^2})$ to $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh indeed. You are correct. Sorry. I read too fast.

Comment: Thank you cs89, yeah I'm afraid it's for the closedness of the operator. I have tried choosing a sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}\to f$ in $L^2(0,1)$ and $\{Af_n\}_{n\geq 1} \to g$ in $L^2(0,1)$ such that $g \neq 0$, but I'm having difficulties.

Comment: Thank you both. I adapted the construction to disprove that the graph is closed.

Comment: Nevermind my now deleted comment, good job!

Comment: I didn't get to see your comment in time but I changed a little the construction to be more rigorous.

Comment: It was just that I also went too quickly and thought you didn't show that the operator was not closed, yet you showed that it is not even closable (which is quite interesting), which implies that it's not closed in particular.

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful solution, just worked through the details and it makes a ton of sense.